# Find the max and min element above a threshold in a container

Tags: c++

I have a container that looks like this: `std::map<size_t, std::set<char>>`

I want to find the absolute max element and the min element above a threshold `x`  based on the size of the `std::set`.

I can get the max and min using the following line:

```
auto minMaxElements = std::minmax_element(cbegin(map), cend(map), 
    [](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs){
        return lhs.second.size() < rhs.second.size();
    });
```

Is it possible to get the min element above a threshold `x` using std::minmax_element?

Example:
Say I have a `std::map` of `5` elements. The sizes of the `std::set` values are as `1, 2, 1, 10, and 5`. And I set the threshold as `1`, then I want the max element to give the iterator containing `std::set` of size `10` and the min element to give the iterator containing `std::set` of size `2`.

Comment: Won't sorting be the most efficient way?

Comment: The map is indexed by the `size_t` and I want it to remain that way. I don't want it to make the map using the size of the values.

Comment: What are the possible values in `key` of `map`? If `size_t` specifies the size of `set` which is value part of map, then map won't store all the sets.

Comment: The key is unrelated to the size of the sets.

Comment: You might look at some [range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), then you can do the `std::minmax_element` on *filtered* view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::find_if` to do that

```
auto it = std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), 
   [x](const auto & l) -> bool { 
      return l.second.size() >= x;    // >= or >, depending upon requirement
   }
);
```

Then use this iterator in your `std::minmax_element`

```
auto minMaxElements = std::minmax_element(it, map.end(), 
    [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs) {
        return lhs.second.size() < rhs.second.size();
    }
);
```

Comment: But if I do that, isn't there a chance I can still get a min element below my threshold?

Like, if the sizes are: 1, 2, 1, 10, and 5 (stored in that order in the map). And if the threshold is 1.`auto  it` will point to 2 and end will point to 5. Within that min is 1 and max is 10.

Comment: @user3666471 The `std::find_if` will only iterate to elements those are above the threshold `x`. Try to run it and see the results.